# There is some way to see in which topics users are subscribed on firebase FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing FCM on application and want to know if there's any way to see in which topics users tokens are subscribed ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to record topic subscriptions on your own.  Subscriptions are registered per device, not per user (one user could be using multiple devices, each with different subscriptions).  It's common for apps to manage a mapping between users, device tokens, and subscriptions in a database (such as Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore).